# Merge conflict take source but keep target changes

Tags: git, visual-studio, merge, team-explorer

In my project i got `develop` and master `branch`. In develop for `Person`'s class i've added one property `HairColors` and on master i've added `SkinColor` property. I would like to make a `merge` from `develop` to `master` and take property `HairColors` but keep `SkinColor`. If i choose `TakeSource` it will remove `SkinColor` but takes `HairColors` and when i choose `TakeTarget` it does `viceversa`. What to do in this case?

P.S WHat are both "Diff" options?

[image: Merge scren]

Comment: I didn't understand the P.S. question about diffs. I guess that's also editor related?

Comment: @mimikrija yes yes

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the editor. For example, Visual Studio Code gives you an option to "keep both changes" when opening a file containing merge conflicts.

But to understand what actually happens beneath the surface (what you see in the editor is just their interpretation of the file containing merge conflicts), try opening the file in a simple(r) text editor: You will then notice some `<<<` and `>>>` and `===` markers around the merge conflict. Remove the markers manually, save the file. Then run `git add Person.cs` and, if this was your only unresolved conflict, `git merge --continue`.

`git add` stages the file, and `git merge --continue` is commiting your change (manual conflict resolution) as well as any other files changed as a result of the merge, to a so-called merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to keep both sides of the conflict, it requires manual intervention.  You will need to merge the changes in the merge editor.  It cannot be done automatically because there is a conflict where the exact same lines in the file were changed in both branches.

When you click the Merge button in Team Explorer, it'll open the file in the merge editor.  You should then see checkboxes by each conflict that allow you to keep the content from that side.  In this case, you should check the checkbox on both sides.  That should result in both HairColors and SkinColor being preserved in the lower (result) pane in the merge editor.

The lower pane is editable, so you can make any manual tweaks to the result content before you accept the merge, which saves the file.